# CSS grid y HTML semantico

Tags: css-grid-layout, semantic-html

Estoy aprendiendo CSS grid y al intentar usarlo junto con HTML semantico me resulto el siguiente problema.

https://codepen.io/oscarryz/pen/oNNBKyd

Básicamente tengo esto

```
  <div class="grid-container">
    <header>
      <div class="header"></div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="content"></div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Y quiero un grid de 3x3 con la primera y ultima columna como espacio vacío

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 40em 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    " . header . "
    " . content . "
    " . footer . ";
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

Si quito el html semántico [funciona](https://codepen.io/oscarryz/pen/abbpeLw) pero la intención es mantenerlo.

Cual es la manera correcta de hacerlo?